# Como Adicionar Botão meu slide

Tags: javascript, css

Comecei a estudar HTML e CSS agora. Porém preciso fazer um slide e achei um cédigo pronto, mas precisava que ele tivesse aqueles botões redondos pequenos embaixo centralizado no meio. É para versão mobile. Alguem saberia como faço?

```js
<script type = "text/javascript" > // <![CDATA[
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.customer-logos').slick({
      slidesToShow: 4,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      autoplay: true,
      autoplaySpeed: 1500,
      arrows: false,
      dots: false,
      pauseOnHover: false,
      responsive: [{
        breakpoint: 768,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 3
        }
      }, {
        breakpoint: 520,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 1
        }
      }]
    });
  });
// ]]></script>
```

```css
<style><!-- div#banner {}

.banner img {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}


/* Slider */

.slick-slide {
  margin: 0px 5px;
}

.slick-slide img {
  width: 100%;
}

.slick-slider {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
  touch-action: pan-y;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

.slick-list {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.slick-list:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.slick-list.dragging {
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: hand;
}

.slick-slider .slick-track,
.slick-slider .slick-list {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.slick-track {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
}

.slick-track:before,
.slick-track:after {
  display: table;
  content: '';
}

.slick-track:after {
  clear: both;
}

.slick-loading .slick-track {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.slick-slide {
  display: none;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 1px;
}

[dir='rtl'] .slick-slide {
  float: right;
}

.slick-slide img {
  display: block;
}

.slick-slide.slick-loading img {
  display: none;
}

.slick-slide.dragging img {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.slick-initialized .slick-slide {
  display: block;
}

.slick-loading .slick-slide {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.slick-vertical .slick-slide {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.slick-arrow.slick-hidden {
  display: none;
}

--></style>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</p>
<div class="banner"><img alt="" src="{{media url=" wysiwyg/teste/categorias/kitbody.png "}}" /></div>
<div class="customer-logos">
  <div class="slide">
    <a href="/roupas-de-bebes/departamento/bermuda+calca+mij_o"><img alt="" src="{{media url=" wysiwyg/teste/categorias/Mijoes.png "}}" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <a href="/higiene-bebe"><img alt="" src="{{media url=" wysiwyg/teste/categorias/Higiene.png "}}" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <a href="/alimentacao-bebe"><img alt="" src="{{media url=" wysiwyg/teste/categorias/alimenta_o.png "}}" /></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo link do CDN do JavaScript que vc postou na pergunta me parece que vc está usando o plugin de slider **slick-carousel** http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Na documentação para vc ativar as "bolinhas de navegação" os `dots` deve estar como `true` (`dots: true`)!

Veja o *script* abaixo como deve ser configurado, repare onde deixei o comentário.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.customer-logos').slick({
      slidesToShow: 4,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      autoplay: true,
      autoplaySpeed: 1500,
      arrows: false,
      dots: true,            //aqui deve ser TRUE e não FALSE como estava...
      pauseOnHover: false,
      responsive: [{
        breakpoint: 768,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 3
        }
      }, {
        breakpoint: 520,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 1
        }
      }]
    });
  });
```

Comment: Muitooo obrigado, resolveu meu problema!

Comment: @JVEUZEBIO que bom que deu certo! Se a minha resposta te ajudou de alguma forma considere marca-la como Aceita, nesse ícone ✔ abaixo das setinhas no lado esquerdo da minha resposta :) assim o site não fica com perguntas abertas pendentes sem resposta aceita.

Comment: certo, vou marca, só mais uma pergunta o slidesToShow: 3 é responsável por quantas imagens mostram de uma vez ?

Comment: @JVEUZEBIO sim. E aquela parte final do código quer dizer que quando a tela estiver com 768px ele mostra 3 imgs, e quando a tela tiver 520px de largura vai mostrar 1 img. Para telas maiores que 768px isso serão 4 imgs como está no início do script em `slidesToShow: 4,`